# IF statement is just not working

Tags: java, android, return

I'm writing an android app that does a lot of stuff. I recently refactored my code to have a better structure, but suddenly I'm getting a very strange problem.

```
handleRequest(String str)
{
    boolean foo = executeCommand(str);
    this.publishProgress("FOO1: " + foo);

    if (foo == false);
    {
        this.publishProgress("FOO2: " + foo);
        sendString("Failed to execute: " + str);
    }

    this.publishProgress("FOO3: " + foo);
    sendEOM();
}
```

The code above should execute a command, and store 'foo' with if the command was executed correctly. This code is inside an Android AsyncTask (thread) so I use 'publishProgress' to show a toast.

I've been flipping through the debugger and FOO is true! The toasts show FOO to be true the entire way through as well. However, it goes ahead and jumps inside the IF block and executes that too. I've never seen this before, I think its a problem with Java. I was stepping though the function 'executeCommand' and it looks like it is skipping return statements too.

I've ran the code on a virtual device and a real one and they both do this.

Any ideas? I'm completely at a loss here.

Comment: remove the semicolon after the if statement

Comment: Not your problem, but cleaner and clearer to use `if (!foo)` instead.

Comment: @dimo414 Right, I was getting frustrated by the time I posted this, so I changed it to "FOO == FALSE" just so that it was so explict I couldn't have seen anything wrong.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You said

```
 if (foo == false);
```

remove the semicolon, it should be

```
 if (foo == false) {//your code}
```

Comment: Oh man, I feel like an idiot. I can't believe missed that semicolon in there! I spent a lot of time debugging 'executeCommand' thinking the problem was up there... Anyway, thanks for spotting that for me!

Answer (score 9):

Remove the semicolon: `if (foo == false);` -> `if (foo == false)`

Answer (score 9):

You put a semicolon after `if` statement.

That way, your `if` statement is there on its own, and the following block of code is always running.

Modify your code like this:

```
handleRequest(String str) {
    boolean foo = executeCommand(str);
    this.publishProgress("FOO1: " + foo);

    if (foo == false) {
        this.publishProgress("FOO2: " + foo);
        sendString("Failed to execute: " + str);
    }

    this.publishProgress("FOO3: " + foo);
    sendEOM();
}
```

N.B.
Keeping your block-opening braces in the same line as the function definition/loop condition makes these kinds of mistakes much less frequent, IMO.

Answer (score 4):

There will be no ";" semicolon after if statement.

So instead of if `(foo == false);`  it should be  if `(foo == false){}`

Answer (score 4):

If you write semicolon (;) after if statement it ends the if condition there!
you need to start a block of code after writing if condition i.e.

```
if(foo == false){

// block of Code

} //end of if condition
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how this line compiles `if (foo == false);`, but evidently it does. You need to remove the semicolon at the end of the line as others have mentioned. With the ; there it means do nothing if foo is false. Then the program goes into the next block between the two curly braces. 
You need to install findbugs or PMD to warn against this kind of typos.